# Why angular redirects to the route but loads the wrong view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a basic need I wanted to address with routes:

1. A bunch of routes defined
2. If the user is not authenticated, then he's redirected to the login page

My problem is that, the **first time** the web app is displayed, the user seem to be correctly redirected because **the URI is correct, but not the displayed view** (it corresponds to the default view).

[I've created a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gudifutevi/1/edit?html,js) for that, if you prefer to see it for real. The [result can be viewed here](http://jsbin.com/gudifutevi/1).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load the page
2. You see *needsAuth*, meaning that the content of the view `needsAuth` is displayed even if the URI contains *login* (which corresponds to the view `login`)
3. Reload the page
4. You see 'login', meaning that the content of the view `login`

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
var template = '{{vm.text}}';

angular
  .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', routes])
  .controller('needsAuthController', needsAuthController)
  .controller('loginController', loginController)
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', registerRedirection]);

function routes($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/needsAuth', {
      controller: 'needsAuthController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      template: template
    })
    .when('/login', {
      controller: 'loginController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      template: template
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/needsAuth'
    });
}

function needsAuthController(){
  var vm = this;

  vm.text = 'needsAuth';
}

function loginController(){
  var vm = this;

  vm.text = 'login';
}

function registerRedirection($rootScope, $location){
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next){
    $location.path('/login');
  });
}
```

On the first load, you can see that URI and content do not match
[image: Result on first load]

If I reload the page, everything is working as expected:
[image: Result after reloading the page]

Is there something I'm doing wrong? If it's the case, what is the correct way to redirect user under some conditions?

[Edit]: Angular 1.2.26 seems to behave correctly in this case, but not angular 1.3.2

Comment: Why you redirect all the requests to login page?

Comment: you controllers and run declaration are weird, never saw something like that maybe try to write the code directly under declarations not with functions

Comment: @anguLaravel because it's not real code, just the minimal code to reproduce the bug. In the real one, I'm testing if the user is authenticated, then redirect if it's not the case.

Comment: @Charlie: it's the same, and it's more legible like that. You can take a look at these guidelines to know more: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Comment: Angular 1.3 dont work anymore with function declerations of controllers.

Comment: @anguLaravel: this notation is equivalent to putting all the declaration in the same call. In the end, you're always writing a function. Take a look at the guidelines I linked in a previous comment.

Comment: @ghusse have you tried using `$stateChangeSuccess` instead? Redirect detection is probably disabled in the start event to prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: @LoganMurphy he does not work with ui.router

Comment: But i think what @LoganMurphy said will work try change to $routeChangeSuccess

Comment: @LoganMurphy: it works! Thanks, even if it's weird

Comment: To repeat what Mawg said, can you please award the answer so as to help others in the future? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
function registerRedirection($rootScope, $location){
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next){
       $location.path('/login');
   });
}
```

To

```
function registerRedirection($rootScope, $location){
   $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next){     

                     ^ change this ^    

       $location.path('/login');
   });
}
```

And then your initial load works correctly.

Comment: I cannot see what you changed! Did you forget something?

Comment: Sorry, should've made it more obvious! changed $routeChangeStart to $locationChangeStart

Comment: Then please award the answer. Doing so will help others in future

Comment: This answer worked for me as well, can you just elaborate a little on what it actually does? Thank you!

Comment: And why this weird redirect occurs in the first place?